# Contrary vs Converse when used as a noun

Tags: word-choice

**Q:** Which is the better word to be used in the following sentence?

> My history seems to indicate the **contrary** in that my hypertension was the cause of my anger & stress.

...or...

> My history seems to indicate the **converse** in that my hypertension was the cause of my anger & stress.

---

This question stems from an edit of another [stackexchange question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/can-high-blood-pressure-cause-a-bad-temper) where someone updated my text from the term "contrary" to "converse". I changed it back, but now am second guessing myself.

When I [looked up "converse"](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=define%20converse) it is defined as:

```
noun archaic
ˈkänˌvərs/
    conversation.
```

...but it seems there are some mathematical uses for the [term "converse" in terms of logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_%28logic%29).

> In logic, the converse of a categorical or implicational statement is the result of reversing its two parts.

Which is the better word in this context?

Comment: 'Converse' _is_ perhaps more regularly used as a stand-alone noun than 'contrary'. With the set expression 'indicate the contrary', the situation seems reversed [[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indicate+the+contrary%2Cindicate+the+converse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindicate%20the%20contrary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindicate%20the%20converse%3B%2Cc0)] (but this is raw data).

Comment: Personally, I've never heard "converse" used as a noun before. I didn't even know it meant something other than "conversation" (i.e. "to converse"). I know of "contrary" specifically from Sherlock Holmes (i.e. "On the contrary, my dear Watson..."). Surprised to hear that "converse" is actually more commonly used in literature.

Answer (score 1):

Although both `converse` and `contrary` seems okay to use, `contrary` sounds more natural probably because people use it more. +1 for `contrary`.

Answer (score 1):

Your "logical" definition is the applicable one. The converse of a statement is one in which the order of the two terms is reversed: "No B is A" is the converse of "No A is B", and vice versa. This is not (necessarily) the same as "contrary" - having the opposite meaning. For "No A is B", the contrary is either "All A are B" or "Some A are B", depending on how logically-minded you are, with the common use leaning towards "All A are B".

In this particular case, either contrary or converse is correct, since "A caused B" is both contrary to and the converse of "B caused A".

But I'd agree with stevanity, and go with contrary - it sounds more natural.

Comment: Applying *categorical converse* does not feel appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The word *converse* is more precise to a linguist or logician, but there is nothing wrong with your use of *contrary*. Both are correct in your use case, and are commonly treated as synonyms of each other.

As you saw in your research, the logical converse of *X caused Y* is exactly *Y caused X*.

However, there are four opposites to *X caused Y*: *¬X caused Y*, *X caused ¬Y*, *Y caused X*, and *X is not related to Y*. Each of these could be considered the contrary of the original statement.

Comment: Since 'converse' is defined by Collins as 'n
2. _something that is opposite or contrary_', and that these senses are given before the stricter logical ones, it could be argued that 'the converse of X caused Y is X did not cause Y'.

Comment: I grant the two terms are treated synonymously conversationally.